# i18n.language is undefined in the url

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have a language detection mechanism from the url lang code. If user is accessing authenticated page without access token, I redirect to login page in the Routes.js.

```
return user ? (  
      <Component {...props} />  
    ) : (  
      <Redirect to={langUrl(`login`)} />  
    );
```

LangUrl is a helper function to get url with correct lang code

```
export const langUrl = (url) => {
  return '/'+ i18n.language +'/'+ url;
};
```

But I get an undefined in the i18n.language, the redirect url is "/undefined/login". My i18n init file is below

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'

i18n
.use(HttpApi)
.use(LanguageDetector)
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'ar'],
    fallbackLng: 'ar',
    debug: false,
    // Options for language detector
    detection: {
        order: ['path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag'],
        caches: ['cookie'],
    },
    react: { useSuspense: false },
    defaultNS: 'translation',
    backend: {
        loadPath: '/assets/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
});

export default i18n;
```

What is the best way to initiliaze the i18n correctly so that language is not undefined?

Comment: Do you have a default language set? I think you probably need to specify `lng` and `fallbackLng` so that you have an initial language set.

Comment: I have a fallbak lang set as ar, if we specify lng it will stop language detection from url right?

Answer (score 1):

adding the following value  **initImmediate: false,** in i18n config file
please check the full answer here
[i18n.language undefined in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69213646/i18n-language-undefined-in-react-js/73302565#73302565)