# i18n.language undefined in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I am trying to use a custom i18n setup but it's says undefined, but when I print the object has the values, how can this be solved.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  .use(backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] !== 'en' ? 'de' : 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    whitelist: ['en', 'de'],
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    backend: {
      loadPath:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
          : '/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      addPath:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? '/locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
          : '/static/locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      crossDomain: true,
    },

    ns: 'translations',
    defaultNS: 'translations',

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: undefined,
      unescapePrefix: undefined,
      nestingOptionsSeparator: undefined,
    },
    keySeparator: false,
    nsSeparator: false,
    pluralSeparator: undefined,
    contextSeparator: undefined,
  });

export default i18n;
```

This is how I use it :

import i18n from 'i18n';

```
export const defaultCountryByLanguage = () =>
  i18n.language === 'en'
    ? { country: 'Germany', code: 'DE', prefix: '49', nationality: 'German' }
    : { country: 'Deutschland', code: 'DE', prefix: '49', nationality: 'Deutsch' };
```

The ternary operator doesn't work because `i18n.language` says it's null, yet when I print it shows the values.

Answer (score 1):

please try to add **initImmediate: false,** to your config

Set it to false if your backend loads resources synchronously - that way.

for more details check the documents https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options

your config should be like this

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  .use(backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] !== 'en' ? 'de' : 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    whitelist: ['en', 'de'],
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    backend: {
      loadPath:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
          : '/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      addPath:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? '/locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
          : '/static/locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      crossDomain: true,
    },

    ns: 'translations',
    defaultNS: 'translations',

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: undefined,
      unescapePrefix: undefined,
      nestingOptionsSeparator: undefined,
    },
    keySeparator: false,
    nsSeparator: false,
    pluralSeparator: undefined,
    contextSeparator: undefined,
////add inside config
    initImmediate: false,
  });

export default i18n;
```

[image]

Comment: This only works for compatible backends, like i18next-fs-backend